# How to call user control panel in American English?

Tags: localization, internationalization

How do I call the control panel in a business directory website, except "control panel"?

Initially we thought of "My Office", but it revealed a bad idea as soon as I needed to write "Welcome to your My Office" ("welcome to My Office" is no good either: it invites the user to someone else's office :-).

I've seen versions like "Personal Room", but can't say whether they sound OK in American English.

Comment: Not much, but this is web development, and people here must be familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Administration?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "Welcome to your office"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "User Settings"?